# participle with different subjects

Tags: grammar, participle-clauses

I think a participle clause and main clause  having different subjects is exception to the rule of participles. I found the following sentences in a grammar book and in some internet resources which I suppose to have different subjects:

1. The weather being nice, we decided to go for a picnic.
2. It being a cloudy night, I couldn't see the moon.
3. Saroj being late, I couldn't catch the bus.

All of them contain "being". It would seem that we can use different subjects in participle clause and in main clause with the help of being. Are they correct sentences to use? Are there any other conditions when we can use different subjects in a participle clause and in main clause, or in subbordinate clause and main clause?
I've read this source too: https://english.lingolia.com/en/grammar/sentences/participle-clauses

Comment: He having no money on his person, we decided not to rob him. They wearing such large hats, we couldn't see the stage. The smell of the burst sewer lines filling the school, they opted to evacuate.

Comment: There is nothing specific to the verb form "being" that makes these present participle clauses different than clauses that use the participles of other verbs. _The weather feeling nice..._ or _It looking like a cloudy night_ or _Sanjo running late_ are all similarly _present participle clauses._

Comment: Notice that all the phrases you mentioned include a subject to avoid a _dangling structure_. If you remove the subject of the phrase then you'll have a dangling phrase.

Comment: @yubrajsharma Can you tell us what "rule of participles" you refer to here?

Comment: @P.E Dent Rule of participle refers to the genaral rule,"subject of the participle clause can't be different than the main clause".

Comment: It's not a rule, really. The main clause's subject has to be capable of or affected by the action in the participle clause, or connected to it somehow by context. _The book having 200 pages, my goldfish died._ would only be possible in the autobiography of an author who, in the course of finishing his novel, neglected to feed his goldfish.

Comment: @P.E Dent, Being imployed to teaching in a school,I hardly have time for paintings." Is it cortrect?

Comment: Yes... with a few corrections: _"Being **e**mployed **in** teaching **at** a school, I hardly have time for painting." (Note: _painting_ is singular.)

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction

Answer (score 5):

Based on [Longman English Grammar](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://hcot.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Longman_English_Grammar.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjL_8OLksLPAhVIVBQKHZxNATEQFggcMAA&usg=AFQjCNHL_1mrFi2Y33lH-VVjDRF4KSY_cw&sig2=PYRd6sY6k6itoYPE2XYR5w), page 32, you can use participle constructions after *there* and *it*. However, it occurs in formal style.

> It being a bank holiday all the shops were shut. (i.e. As it was ...)
>
> There being no further business I declared the meeting closed. (i.e. As there is ...)

That remains true with subjects other than *it* and *there*, too. In other words it's going to be very formal to use [participle clauses with different subjects](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/participles) as in

> (With) Mrs Jones going to New York, Mr Smith took up her position.

Source: [English Grammar Online](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/participles)

As P. E. Dant well pointed out, *there is nothing specific to the verb form "being"*. you can use other verb forms in your participle which do not share the same subject as the one of your independent clause although it's not common use. It's simply very formal.

(*By the way, I didn't know that. Thanks for asking this question. It made me learn something new*)

Answer (score 2):

These are called ***Absolute phrases***, which are noun phrases (usually a noun plus a participle phrase ) working as adverbs modifyingthe the verbs of tha main clauses like any other adverbs.