# Noun + being + adj grammar rule

Tags: grammar

In the book "The Forsyte Saga" there is such sentence: "... they did not die; death being contrary to their principles, they took precautions against it..."

I'd like to know which grammar rule is used in the part "death **being** contrary to their principles" ?

Comment: Do you want to know the name of the rule or you just don't understand what the passage in question is saying?

Comment: @CookieMonster the rule and an explanation. The meaning of the sentence I understand.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what this grammar rule is called because I simply don't know, but I can try and explain to you what it's actually saying. Consider the following example:

> "Always help people in need" being their motto, they rushed into the burning house to save the boy.

I hope you can see that **"always help people in need" being their motto** structurally corresponds to **death being contrary to their principles** in your example. It tells you the reason why the people in this passage rushed into the burning house to save the boy. The reason was because *"Always help people in need"* was their motto. So, they were in a sense obliged to do what they had to do.

We can now apply the same logic to your example and ask the following question: why did they take precautions against it? The answer would be: the reason they took precautions against it was because death was contrary to their principles.

Well, I guess technically you could say that it's a type of adverbial clause that modifies the main clause. In other words, it tells you the reason why the action in the main clause is done. Honestly, that's really all I can say about this.

Answer (score 0):

It's called an absolute construction. And it's already been mentioned in several questions in this site including this one "[Understanding absolute construction](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105900/understanding-absolute-construction)", where there's this useful link "[Prof .Rajappan's English Lessons](http://profrajappansblog.blogspot.kr/2010/10/participial-construction-absolute.html?m=1)", which in part says this:

> What is an absolute phrase? Well, it is different from participial
>   phrases in that it explicitly mentions the subject. The subject is
>   never mentioned in participial phrases . For example, "being rich" is
>   a participial phrase , "he being rich" is an absolute phrase . Another
>   difference between participial construction and absolute construction
>   is that the subjects of absolute phrases are always different from
>   those of their main clauses . For this reason the syntactic relation
>   between the absolute phrase and the main clause is always a fragile
>   one . Hence the name absolute construction . You know absolute means
>   "independent" or "not related " etc . The absolute phrases serves to
>   give additional details in a hurried manner, so to speak .
>   Nonetheless, there is a strong semantic relation between the absolute
>   phrase and the main clause .

In a nutshell, when a participial construction has its own subject, it's called an absolute construction.

You might also want to look at the answer(s) to the earlier question cited above.